# How to take data from another table in firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Hello i have two tables namely "routes" and "busstops" in firebase. I want to retrive another data when i click on a card to the other page but im getting error. The data is being asked to be called in the CustomCard class but it is not the correct database.

Home Page to display card which works fine:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => new _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      // appBar: new AppBar(
      //   title: new Text('Home',),
      // ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.red[400],
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: Firestore.instance.collection('routes').snapshots(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot){
              if (snapshot.hasError)
                return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
              switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                  return new Text('Loading....');
                default:
                  return new ListView(
                    children: snapshot.data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                      return new CustomCard(
                        //name: document['name'],
                        routenum: document['routenum'].toString(),
                        from: document['from'],
                        to: document['to'],
                        via: document['via'],
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  );
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
class CustomCard extends StatelessWidget {
  CustomCard({@required  this.routenum, this.from, this.to, this.via, });

  final routenum;
  final from;
  final to;
  final via;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
        color: Colors.white,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ),
        elevation: 25,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(12),
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  //builder: (context) => Stations(),
                  builder: (context) => BusInfo(routenum: routenum, from: from, to: to, via: via, ), 
                )
            );
          },
          child: Container(

            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("Route Number :" +" " + routenum, style: GoogleFonts.baloo(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
              fontSize: 15,
              ),
            ),
            RichText(
              text: TextSpan(
                text: 'From : ',
                style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                children: <TextSpan>[
                  TextSpan(
                    text: '$from',
                    style: GoogleFonts.viga(
                      color: Colors.blue[800],
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    ),
                  ),
                ]
              ),
            ),
            Text("via" + " " + via , style: GoogleFonts.poppins(),
            ),
            RichText(
              text: TextSpan(
                text: 'To : ',
                style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                children: <TextSpan>[
                  TextSpan(
                    text: '$to',
                    style: GoogleFonts.viga(
                      color: Colors.blue[800],
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    ),
                  ),
                ]
              ),
            ),
            Text("(or Vice Versa)", style: GoogleFonts.montserrat()),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

And below is the code that i want to to bring the data which is busstations in my firebase:

```
class Stations extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _StationsState createState() => _StationsState();
}

class _StationsState extends State<Stations> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          //color: Colors.red[400],
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: Firestore.instance.collection('busstops').snapshots(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot){
              if (snapshot.hasError)
                return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
              switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                  return new Text('Loading....');
                default:
                  return new ListView(
                    children: snapshot.data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                      return new CustomTable(
                        //name: document['name'],
                        title: document['title'],
                        station1: document['station1'],
                        station2: document['station2'],
                        station3: document['station3'],
                        station4: document['station4'],
                        station5: document['station5'],
                        station6: document['station6'],
                        station7: document['station7'],
                        station8: document['station8'],
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  );
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
class CustomTable extends StatelessWidget {
  CustomTable({@required this.title, this.station1, this.station2, this.station3, this.station4, this.station5, this.station6, this.station7, this.station8});

  final title;
  final station1;
  final station2;
  final station3;
  final station4;
  final station5;
  final station6;
  final station7;
  final station8;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        Center(
          child: Text(
            title,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

This is where i want the data from bussops to be displayed in tablele form instead of routes.

```
class BusInfo extends StatelessWidget {
  BusInfo({@required this.routenum, this.from, this.to, this.via});

  final routenum;
  final from;
  final to;
  final via;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(routenum),
            backgroundColor: Color(0xFFBDBDBD),
            elevation: 3,
            bottom: TabBar(indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label, tabs: [
              Tab(
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Text("Route Info"),
                ),
              ),
              Tab(
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Text("Timetable"),
                ),
              ),
            ]),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(children: [
             Center(
          child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(routenum),
                Text(from),
                Text(via),
                Text(to),
                RaisedButton(
                    child: Text('Back To HomeScreen'),
                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context)),
              ]),
        ),
            Icon(Icons.movie),
            // Icon(Icons.games),
          ]),
        ))
     );
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean Firestore and Collections, instead of Firebase and Tables?

Comment: In fact i have a card and i have retrieve data in it from the collections in the firestore, now i have created a new table and i want to retrieve its collections tothe page businfo.dart

Comment: OK, But is there any problem with doing it analogically to the card? BTW there are no tables in Firestore, but I understand this is a collection.

Comment: noo there is no problem with the card it gives me what i have in collections, but i want to pu to retriev the collections of busstops in the businfo.dart, in the Route Info tab